# How to add attribute on load and change value when clicking an element with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to add attribute **"aria-label=test1"** when it is **fa-chevron-left** and **"aria-label=test2"** on **fa-chevron-right**.

**fa-chevron-left** (see image) would be there on load and **"aria-label=test1"** should be there on load as well (default). The function is to collapse and expand the table of contents.

This element is clickable and I want the aria-label value to change dynamically.

[image]

Here is my existing JavaScript code:

```js
function r() {
        const e = document.querySelector(".slide-btn");
        e.getBoundingClientRect().x < window.innerWidth / 2 ? (e.classList.add("left"), e.classList.remove("right")) : (e.classList.remove("left"), e.classList.add("right"));
    }
function s(e) {
          const t = n(),
            c = document.querySelector(".nav-container"),
            o = document.querySelector(".content-container"),
            s = document.querySelector(".slide-btn i.fas");
          switch (e) {
            case "toggle":
              c.classList.toggle("slided"),
                s.classList.toggle("fa-chevron-right"),
                s.classList.toggle("fa-chevron-left"),
                t && o.classList.toggle("slided");
              break;
            case "show":
              c.classList.remove("slided"),
                s.classList.remove("fa-chevron-right"),
                s.classList.add("fa-chevron-left"),
                t && o.classList.add("slided");
              break;
            case "hide":
              if (c.classList.add("slided"), s.classList.add("fa-chevron-right"), s.classList.remove("fa-chevron-left"), t) {
                o.classList.remove("slided");
                const e = document.querySelector(".body-container").getAttribute("activeTopic");
                document.getElementById(e).scrollIntoView()
              }
          }
        }
```

Here is the existing HTML code:

```html
<div class="slide-btn left" style="height: 749px;">
<i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i> 
</div>
```

I've added this code below `s = document.querySelector(".slide-btn i.fas");`:

```js
s.setAttribute("aria-label", s.classList.contains("fa-chevron-left") ? "test1" : "test2");
```

However, the attribute and value does not appear on load. It only appears and changes when I click the **fa-chevron-left**. Is there a way I can make the **aria-label** show on load and change value when I click **fa-chevron-left** and **fa-chevron-right**?

Comment: You need to add HTML code also without html no one can play with your JS code.

Comment: I've added my HTML code

Comment: where is **click()** event method?

Comment: This is the click() event method -
document.querySelector(".slide-btn").addEventListener("click", (() => {
                    s("toggle")
                }));

Comment: I added working snippet below. so check how this working...

Answer (score 0):

`element.matches('.classname')` from this method to get true or false. If class name is exist then return true otherwise false. So I used for checking class is exist or not from **.matches()** method & from **.setAttebute()** to set attribute value like: `element.setAttribute('attribute-name', 'attribute value')`

```js
function r() {
    const e = document.querySelector(".slide-btn");
    e.getBoundingClientRect().x < window.innerWidth / 2 ? (e.classList.add("left"), e.classList.remove("right")) : (e.classList.remove("left"), e.classList.add("right"));
}
function s(e) {
    const t = r(), /*n() to r()*/
        c = document.querySelector(".nav-container"),
        o = document.querySelector(".content-container"),
        s = document.querySelector(".slide-btn i.fas");
    switch (e) {
        case "toggle":
            c.classList.toggle("slided");

            /*Check class is exist or not*/  
            if(s.matches('.fa-chevron-right')){
                s.classList.remove("fa-chevron-right");
                s.classList.add("fa-chevron-left");
                s.setAttribute("aria-label","test1"); /*add attribute*/
            }else{
                s.classList.remove("fa-chevron-left");
                s.classList.add("fa-chevron-right");
                s.setAttribute("aria-label", "test2"); /*add attribute*/
            }

            t && o.classList.toggle("slided");
            break;
        case "show":
            c.classList.remove("slided"),
            s.classList.remove("fa-chevron-right"),
            s.classList.add("fa-chevron-left"),
            s.setAttribute("aria-label", "test1");

            t && o.classList.add("slided");
            break;
        case "hide":
            if (c.classList.add("slided"), s.classList.add("fa-chevron-right"), s.classList.remove("fa-chevron-left"), t) {
                o.classList.remove("slided");
                const e = document.querySelector(".body-container").getAttribute("activeTopic");
                document.getElementById(e).scrollIntoView()
            }
    }
}

/*show --> On page load */
s("show"); 

/* toggle --> on click event */ 
document.querySelector(".slide-btn").addEventListener("click", (() => { s("toggle") }));
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css"/>
        

<div class="nav-container">
    <div class="content-container">
        <div class="slide-btn left" style="height: 749px;">
            <i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am getting this error for s("show"); - Uncaught TypeError: s is not a function. I am unable to change const t = r() because I have other script that is dependant on const t = n()

Comment: Can you mentioned *n()* function? So I can debug for this type of error.